# How to confirm if the record's value fit the partition scheme in dolphindb?

Tags: database, date, types, partition, dolphindb

I create a partitioned table. For example:

```
n=1000000
month=take(2000.01M..2016.12M, n)
x=rand(1.0, n)
t=table(month, x)
db=database("dfs://valuedb", VALUE, 2000.01M..2016.12M)
pt = db.createPartitionedTable(t, `pt, `month)
```

So the record's column 'month' should between 2000.01M..2016.12M.11. But I find that I can also insert the record with the value of 'month' is type DATE(not MONTH) in dolphindb:

```
t1 = table(2010.01.15 as month , 10 as x)
pt.append!(t1)
```

So how can I confirm if the record's value fit the partition scheme?

Answer (score 0):

When the data type of partition column in database partitioning scheme is different from the data type of corresponding column in table, DolphinDB will try best to perform a implicit conversion. In your example, DATE type will be converted to MONTH type.